# MVC5 relative path not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2, razor-3

I update my web application to MVC5.
Since it requires Razor 3.0 then I updated it as well.

Suddenly relative paths are not resolved anymore, in _layout.cshtml a link like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/main.min.css" />
```

is ok while rendering the home page http://example.com , but it's not referring the root when rendering a page like this 
          http://example.com/level1/test

The link is resolved as: root/level1/Content/main.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason, here's a link that explains it very well: [URL rewrite issues with ASP.NET Razor 3](http://madskristensen.net/post/url-rewrite-may-break-aspnet-razor-3)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using @Url.Content?

e.g

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/main.min.css")" />
```

Or perhaps

```
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/main.min.css")
```

replacing the whole < link > tag